# Laravel Swagger docs not loading in docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, swagger

I've recently tried to dockerize my Laravel project and everything works fine, except for swagger docs that can't run!
so I'm using php 8.1, darkaonline/l5-swagger 8.4 and my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap
RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    #PHP Service
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: digitalocean.com/php
        container_name: app
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        environment:
            SERVICE_NAME: app
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
        networks:
            - app-network

    #Nginx Service
    webserver:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: webserver
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        networks:
            - app-network
#Volumes
volumes:
    dbdata:
        driver: local

#Docker Networks
networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge
```

and this is Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index index.php index.html;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

After `docker compose up -d` all routes work and everything looks fine but swagger http://127.0.0.1/api/docs say's: **unable to load API defenition**!

so I've noticed that running `php artisan l5-swagger:generate` command inside container, doesn't create api-docs.json in storage/api-docs directory

while not using docker and serving regularly, swagger works fine.

What am i doing wrong?

I've tried:
Changing storage directory's permitions,
Using diffrent ports,
clearing laravel cache and ...